# Is this set measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Assume that $\forall x\in E, x$ is a limit point of $E\setminus\{x\}$.

Then, is $E$ Lebesgue-measurable?

For example, any perfect subset, open subset or connected subset are examples of $E$ that are Lebesgue measurable. I cannot think of a counterexample for this.. Is $E$ always Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: What is the source of this question?

Comment: Looks like the standard example at the Example part of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set is a good candidate.

Comment: @Did There's no source.. I'm just curious about it.

Comment: @QuangHoang This one could have isolated points, couldn't it?

Comment: It could? How about taking it and rotate countably many times, but not quite $\mathbb Q$-times?

Comment: @QuangHoang Hmmm... By every dyadic number, say? This sounds promising but one should check that the resulting set is not, rather miraculously, measurable.

Comment: What if you took a non-measurable subset $A$ of the irrationals and set $E=A\cup\Bbb Q$?

Comment: Actually, $A\cup\Bbb Q$ would be a counterexample for any non-measurable $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, such an $E$ need not be measurable:

Let $A$ be a non-measurable set. Then $E=A\cup(\Bbb Q\setminus A)$ is non-measurable (otherwise, $A=\bigl( A\cup (\Bbb Q\setminus A)\bigr) \cap( \Bbb Q\setminus A)^C$ would be measurable).

But, as $\Bbb Q\subset E$, every point $x$ in $E$ is a limit point of $E \setminus\{x\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Lemma: Let $E \subset \Bbb{R}$ be uncountable. There is a countable set $F\subset E$ such that $E\setminus F$ satisfies your assumption.

Proof: Let

$$F := \{x \in E \mid \exists U_x \text{ neighbourhood of } x \text{ s.t. } U_x \cap E \text{ is countable}\}.$$

The open(!) covering $(U_x)_{x \in F}$ of $F$ has a countable subcover $(U_{x_n})_n$, (because $\Bbb{R}$ is 2nd countable), so that $F \subset \bigcup_n U_{x_n} \cap E$ is countable.

For $x \in E\setminus F$ and $U$ neighbourhood of $x$, we know that $E\cap U$ is uncountable. Because $F$ is countable, this yields that $E\setminus (F \cup \{x\})$ is nonempty. $\square$

Now take any nonmeasurable set $N$, choose $F\subset N$ as above. Then $N\setminus F$ is not measurable (why?), but fulfills your assumptions.

Comment: Anything guarantees that $F$ is *not less* than countable? For example: $E=[0,1]$ then $F=\varnothing$.

Comment: It can be "less than" countable. But with my definition of countable, I mean "countably infinite or finite", so that this is the same thing. But there is no problem at all if e.g. $F = \emptyset$.